# Apatana not uploading subdirectories via FTP?

Tags: upload, aptana

I can not get Aptana Studio 3 to upload subdirectories, the folder is created but inside is empty. I'm not receiving any errors in the log file either. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe this is your issue? http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3366